# Как добавить элемент в ListBox в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня не получается добавить элемент в ListBox по нажатию кнопки:

Класс элемента:

```
public class People
{
    public string FirstName {}
    public string LastName {}
}
```

Это лист:

```
private List<People> itemsList = new List<People>();

public List<People> ItemsList
{
    get { return itemsList; }
}
```

Команда для кнопки:

```
AddCommand = new Command(arg => AddMethod());

private void AddMethod()
{
    if (TextProperty1 == "" || TextProperty2 == "")
        {MessageBox.Show("Please write all fields"); return;}

    itemsList.Add(new People(TextProperty1, TextProperty2));
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemsList));

}
```

Код листбокса:

```
<ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="300" Width="750" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0,2">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Grid.Column="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="300" Width="750" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0,2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используй вместо

```
List<People>

ObservableCollection<People>
```

Дело в том, что ObservableCollection при добавлении/удалении элементов кидает событие CollectionChanged, WPF умеет отслеживать данное событие и перерисовывать контрол.

В данном случае контрол не перерисовывается потому, что по факту у тебя источник бинднига не изменяется, т.е. ты добавляешь объект в коллекцию, но сама коллекция ссылается - это тот же самый объект, что и раньше, поэтому, несмотря на то, что ты делаешь OnPropertyChanged реально перерисовки не происходит.

Такой сценарий, как у тебя работал бы, если бы ты сделал так

```
private List<Person>_items = new List<Person>;

publc List<Person> Items
{
    get{ return new List<Person>(_items);}
}
```

В таком случае при обращении к Items всегда будет новый объект и контрол будет перерисовываться. Но все-таки удобнее использовать ObservableCollection.